# "This interaction failed" I can't find the problem at all except this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I clicked the button, he appeared "This interaction failed" but it has the function I want to do, and I don't know why the error occurred.

Function: I want to make a private channel after clicking the button

Question: I can’t stop him from showing "This interaction failed"
,Except for this error, there is no problem, even the function works normally

```
const {
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton,
    Interaction,
    Permissions,
    DiscordAPIError,
    discord
} = require('discord.js');
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js')
const client = require('../index')
const config = require("../config.json");
const { intersection } = require('lodash');
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'tic') {
            if(!client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === interaction.user.username+"-test")){
          
            let channelName = interaction.user.username+"-test";
            interaction.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
            type: "text",
            parent: config.categoryId,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                  id: '887160123733184533', //To make it be seen by a certain role, user an ID instead
                  allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permissions.FLAGS.SEND_MESSAGES, Permissions.FLAGS.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY], //Allow permissions
                  deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE] //Deny permissions
                },{
                    id: '759286092548538388', //To make it be seen by a certain role, user an ID instead
                    deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL] //Deny permissions
                },{
                    id: interaction.user.id,
                    allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permissions.FLAGS.SEND_MESSAGES, Permissions.FLAGS.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY], //Allow permissions
                    deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE] //Deny permissions
                }
            ]
        })
        const del = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('del')
                    .setLabel('️ delete!')
                    .setStyle('DANGER'),
                );
        const welcome = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("test")
        .setDescription("test\n:warning: __**error**__: warn!!!")
        .setColor("#FF5809")
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            const channel123 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === interaction.user.username+"-test");
            channel123.send({
                embeds: [welcome],
                components: [del]
            })
            let a = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("__**test**__")
            .setColor("#00DB00")
            .setDescription(":white_check_mark: test!")
            interaction.user.send({embeds: [a] });
        }, 500)
            
        }else{
            const warn = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RED")
            .setTitle("__**test**__")
            .setDescription(":warning: error!")
        interaction.user.send({embeds: [warn] })
        }
    }
}})
```

If you can tell me the solution, I am very grateful to you

Comment: Could you maybe send the error that happenned too in your code- ? It would be rlly helpful knowing what lign exactly did the problem happenned and you'll get an answer quicker

Comment: I think there should be no way. It did not show any errors. I also put console.log in various places but it came out normally, there was no problem at all, it just appeared "This interaction failed" and there was no error at all.btw thx u

Comment: There's always a way lol don't worry, also could you maybe give me your version of discord.js (also try changing `customID` to just `id`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you never actually *responded* to the interaction. First, defer the reply using [interaction.deferReply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply), this will show a "Bot is thinking" message to the command user. Afterwards, when everything has been done, you reply to it with [interaction.editReply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=editReply).

Comment: Thank you very much, I haven’t found the real reason for a long time, thank you.